# Missing values in difference-in-differences

Tags: paneldata, treatment-effect, difference-in-difference

To give a background of the problem: I'm performing a difference-in-differences analysis to estimate the effect of a treatment, say A. I have a panel data with 5 rounds and about 3000 observations in each round. The treatment was introduced between rounds 2 and 3, thus treated rounds are 3,4,5 while untreated rounds are 1,2. The treatment intensity varies at the level of locality, the data for which have been obtained from a separate administrative source and matched with the survey data. The introduction of the treatment was staggered at the level of locality so I also have a measure of years of exposure to treatment. I intend to obtain the difference-in-difference estimator from interaction between treatment dummy,years of exposure, and treatment intensity.

Now the problem is data for some years (corresponding to round 5 of the survey) are missing in the administrative records. For all the localities, treatment intensity data corresponding to round 5 are missing. Out of these localities, some localities have data on treatment intensity at a later year.

I'm considering using the later year's treatment intensity as a proxy for round 5 treatment intensity for the localities available (which would introduce measurement errors), and leaving the rest of the localities missing on treatment intensity in that round. Can this be done?

Thanks,

Comment: A bit more info would probably be helpful. Is there a reason we could expect treatment intensity in year 6 (or later) to be a rough match for year 5? Are there systematic differences in which localities report intensity in later years? Regarding importance: how much do outcome variables tend to lag the treatment (i.e. do you observe most of your effect in years 3 and 4, or is year 5 critical for your estimate)? Also, to clarify: are all localities in your sample being treated at some point, or do you have a control group that's never treated?

Comment: From the data it can be seen that treatment intensity has fallen significantly in round 4 and the round 6 value for treatment intensity is somewhat higher than round 4 value, but still closer to round 4 value than value in earlier rounds. So one can expect a trend from round 4 to round 6 such that round 5 value can be approximated by round 6 value. As for importance, I am looking at outcomes that manifest over the longer term so round 5 would be critical to my estimate. In my sample, all the localities are being treated so I do not have a control group that is never treated.